# Ocaml syntax error expecting single int if statemnts with pattern matching

Tags: if-statement, design-patterns, pattern-matching, ocaml

When I run the code shown below I get an error that I have also shown below and i am unsure why this is happening

```
let average x y = ((x+y)/2);;



let rec average2 xs = function

| [x,y] -> average x y :: xs

| x :: y :: xs -> if xs = [] then average x y :: xs else average2 xs;;



Error: This expression has type int * int but an expression was expected of type int
```

The letter x in the last line is underlined by this error though when defining the average function it should be retruning just an int to add to the xs list

Thanks for any help

Comment: hehe, this happens to me very often, especially when I do rogue programming in Haskell or Python))

Comment: I don't understand your code. The second line of the pattern matching doesn't mean anything. You say that if xs = [] then average x y :: xs but xs is empty so it's supposedly handled in the first branch and else you call average2 on the rest of the list so you just completely forgot x and y. You'll just end up doing the average of the last two elements of your list. I'm a bit confused on what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used comma (`,`) instead of (`;`) to separate elements of a list. Syntax `[a,b;c,d]` is a shorthand for the `[(a,b);(c,d)]`. So, your first pattern actually corresponds to a singleton list with a pair of elements.

You also have other problems with your function:

### Improper usage of the `function` keyword

The second error is with the improper use of the `function` keyword. Syntax, `let f x = function y -> expr` is the same as `let f x y = expr`. So, your function actually takes two parameters, the `xs` that is never used in the body, and the second one, that is destructed with the pattern matching. What you really meant was:

```
let average2 = function
| ...
```

### Unclear what the function is doing

Your function is actually producing a list, albeit the fact, that an average of a list should be a scalar. Maybe you're trying to find an running average, so that if you have list `[1;3;5;7]` the result would be `[2;6]`.

### Bad cases for pattern matching

You should define your algorithm inductively. Start from simple case, and then move to more complex cases. Assuming, that you're trying to compute a running average of consequent elements:

```
let average2 = function
```

What is the running average of an empty list? We have different possible answers here, we can raise an error, and ask a user to provide an even list of length greater than two, or we can say that it is an empty list.

```
  | [] -> []
```

What is the running average of a singleton list? Let's say that it is the same list:

```
  | [x] -> [x]
```

Now, what is the running average of a list `x1::x2::xs`? It is an average of `x1` and `x2` followed by the running average of `xs`

```
  | x1::x2::xs -> (x1 + x2)/2 :: average2 xs
```

So finally we have:

```
let rec average2 = function
  | [] -> []
  | [x] -> [x]
  | x1 :: x2 :: xs -> (x1 + x2) / 2 :: average2 xs
```

Comment: Thank you very much i didn't even notice, I have changed that but i seem to be getting another error

Comment: Error: This expression has type int list -> int list
       but an expression was expected of type int list

Comment: it says its on the 3rd line of the recursive function

Comment: Thank you so much i hate to keep asking questions but if i remove the xs and just get a syntax error as my xs which is my input has not be defined. I also am not to sure how to solve the problem of the averge x y as i thought that i would work out the average of the two numbers then i would add add it to the empty list?

Answer (score 0):

James

You are probably studying the same module as me, while I had the same assignment.

I can tell you, by far that the answer above is very good for learning, while it doesn't provide the exact solution to your question, but creates an idea of how to do it.

What you are looking for is an alternative function.

You want to input [1;10;15;20] and return [5;12;17], where 5 is the avg between 1 and 10, 12 is the avg of 10 and 15 and 17 is the avg of 15 and 20.

To implement this, you need a secondary function to give you the possibility to reach the secondary value without changing it inside the given list (as it happens if you use `x1::x2::xs -> (x1+x2)/2 :: average2 xs`.

```
let head xs = match xs with 
| [] -> failwith "head" 
| x::xs->x;;
```

Now, you can call it so it returns the secondary element for your average without disrupting the order, so you can pick one element, take on the average in your list and skip to the next one, until you finish.

```
let rec average2 = function
  | [] | [_] -> []
  | x1 :: xs -> (x1 + head xs) / 2 :: average2 xs
```